# Need help on conditional probability problem

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

Assume we have 4% of population having Covid-19, let say P(covid) = 0.04.

And we have these information;

1. Probability of cough symptom found in Covid patients is 75%, P(cough|covid) = 0.75
2. 6.25% of non-Covid population have cough symptom, P(cough|¬covid) = 0.0625

I want to find the probability of detecting positive Covid on an individual with cough symptom.
I start from P(covid|cough) = P(cough|covid) * P(covid) / P(cough), all of the terms are known but the P(cough).

Anyone please help suggest and guide how to solve this problem.

Comment: Imagine you had a population of 1 million.  How many people would you expect to have Covid and a cough?  How many people would you expect to have a cough but not have Covid?  What proportion of those with a cough would you expect to have Covid?

Answer (score 0):

By the law of total probability, `P(cough) = P(cough|covid)*P(covid) + P(cough|¬covid)*P(¬covid)`. It should be no trouble for you to continue from here.

Comment: Thank you. This is simple enough.